# What is the proper way to design a notification system database?

Tags: python, django, notifications

For example, I have following models

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = ...
    avatar = ...

class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = ...
    content = ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # 'Comment' or 'Article'
    target_type = models.CharField()
    target_id = models.IntegerField()
    content = ...

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # 'Comment' or 'Article'
    target_type = models.CharField()
    target_id = models.IntegerField()
```

And the `Notification`:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # 'Comment' or 'Like' or '@'
    verb = models.CharField()
    # Where the notification happens
    source_type = models.CharField()
    source_id = models.IntegerField()
    is_read = ...
    time = ...
```

`source_type` indicates which table I need to look up and `source_id` is the `id` of that `object` (it might be a `Comment` or a `Like` or something else)

And I need serialize the `notification` as below:

```
[
{
    "actor": {
        "username": "Yriuns",
        "avatar": null
    },
    "verb": "Comment",
    "source": {
        "pk": 542,
        "user": {
            "username": "Yriuns",
            "avatar": null
        },
        "content": "this is a reply",
        "time": "2018.11.30 02:38",
        "target": {
            "pk": 540,
            "user": {
                "username": "Someone",
                "avatar": null
            },
            "content": "this is a comment"
        }
    },
    "time": "2018-11-30 02:38:08",
    "is_read": false
},
...
]
```

The problem is: I don't know the efficient way to query database(`MySQL`) to get the `source` field.

For example, there may be 10 notifications and 5 of them are `Comment`, 3 of them are `Like` and 2 of them are `@`. So far I query them one by one, which is really slow.

**Note that** `source` has a `user` field, it should be queried as well.

1. How can I speed up?
2. Did I design the database properly?

I tried `GenericForeignKey`, it works not very well with `prefetch_related` because:

1. Different models have different `ForeignKey`, I can only `prefetch_related` the common ones.
2. I can't use `Prefetch()` object since `GenericForeignKey` doesn't support custom queryset.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Notification` can be a base class for those three you presented (with a common `user` attribute`). Using`InheritanceManager` in [django model utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html) you can query all notifications in a single (not so optimized, but still) query.

Those types and ids also looks like a generic foreign key candidates. Did you look on thank solution?

Comment: I tried `GenericForeignKey`, it works not very well with `prefetch_related` because: 1. Different models have different `ForeignKey`, I can only `prefetch_related` the common ones. 2. I can't use `Prefetch()` object since `GenericForeignKey` doesn't support custom queryset.

Comment: What about the `InheritanceManager`?